Why do larval stages exist in the life cycles of many species? Wouldn't it be better for a species to maintain a single form?
Many organisms undergo multiple distinct developmental stages, each adapted to a different ecological niche. This division of roles can be advantageous, as it allows for both exploration and exploitation of resources. For instance, caterpillars are efficient at feeding and growing, while adult butterflies are better suited to dispersing and finding new habitats. In contrast, tunicate larvae are the ones searching for new habitats.
However, I'm struggling to understand why some species, like the Dungeness crab, produce such vast numbers of small eggs when this argument doesn't seem to apply. Adult crabs are already mobile and capable of finding new habitats. They lay millions of eggs, which hatch into zoeae, then transform into small crabs, and finally mature into adults. If any stage fails to thrive, the species could face extinction. Additionally, if one stage is the most efficient at gathering food, why not maintain that form? Is there a reason crabs can't lay larger eggs due to their exoskeleton?

This question is similar to: Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To answer your last question, the crab body plan allows for significantly larger eggs than we see in dungeness crabs. The Malaysian freshwater crab Isolapotamon baunese lays ~20-80 4 mm eggs despite having a ~6 cm carapace, compared to dungeness crabs that produce millions of < 1 mm eggs with a ~15 cm carapace. These freshwater crabs also move through all the larval stages while still in the egg and hatch as small crabs. In some cases, the mother carries these small crabs long enough for at least one molt. So, if it were advantageous, marine crabs like the dungeness could presumably also evolve to use a single body plan the way you suggest.
This difference between freshwater and marine crabs is probably due to the opportunities available to a life stage as plankton in the ocean compared to the freshwater habitats of these single-form crabs. A study of crab larvae off the coast of Portugal estimated the average crab larva ended up about 70 km from where it hatched. Obviously that kind of distance is impossible in a pond or stream. Also there is a lot of nutrition available in the ocean as plankton, but harvesting it isn't efficient with the body plan of a mature crab.
